# Change a Pivot table Source to a different workbook (based on cell value)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, datasource, auto-update

I have to weekly update a database that has around 15 workbooks.

The solution that I have come up to is to arrange the data with pivot tables (one pivot table for each file) and then consolidate them with a VBA code that copies the data to another single workbook (ALREADY DONE).

The problem is that I need to manually change the data source for all those files, also it takes time to open each of them as they are heavy (10mb).

What would be optimal is a code that changes the source for each file, looking on another folder (April week 1,2,3,4 // May week 1, 2, 3, 4...)

Example **FILE 1**:

Source April Week 3: 'C:\ACreative\April\3[Coop.XLS]Sheet1'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

Source April Week 4: 'C:\ACreative\April\4[Coop.XLS]Sheet1'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

Source May Week 1:  'C:\ACreative\May\1[Coop.XLS]Sheet1'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

Source May Week 2: 'C:\ACreative\May\2[Coop.XLS]Sheet1'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

Example **FILE 2**:

Source April Week 3: 'C:\ACreative\April\3[File2.XLS]Sheet1'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

Source April Week 4: 'C:\ACreative\April\4[File2.XLS]Sheet1'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

Source May Week 1:  'C:\ACreative\May\1[File2.XLS]Sheet1'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

Source May Week 2: 'C:\ACreative\May\2[File2.XLS]Sheet1'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

A solution that I tought was to write the (\April\3\ ; \May\1) on a cell, and update the source based on that "path+cell value", but I am open to another one.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The [Macro Recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-2841ba85-9da6-4bd7-93a4-0da90844f283#bmrecordmacro) is your friend.

As long as you know the different DataSources are all going to slide into the pivot table in question, try the below VBA snippet to quickly switch between either same-workbook or other-workbook ranges.

```
Sub ChangeDataSource()
    Dim DataSource As String
    Dim Green As Long, Red As Long
    Green = -11489280
    Red = -16776961

On Error GoTo ErrHandle

    DataSource = Range("DataSource").Value
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataSource, Version _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15)

    Range("DataSource").Font.Color = Green
    Range("CurrentDataSource").Value = DataSource
    Calculate

    GoTo Success

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox ("DataSource is not valid.")
    Range("DataSource").Font.Color = Red

Success:

End Sub
```

Note I've made some use of named ranges in the local workbook to assist the macro. I've uploaded [some sample files here](https://github.com/petervandivier/hello-world/commit/83607e57b9c1a5c56846f178af7ff56c1593e6ae) rather than uploading screenshots so you can poke around yourself instead of trying to interpret static pictures on the forum post.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Beautiful! Fit as a glove. Thanks!

Comment: Actually... I am having some trouble...

I am not able to change the source when I use the macro on other workbooks...

'C:\ACreative\Análises\Sell Out\REWORKING\Consolidar\Download\Maio\30\[Coop.xlsx]Vendas por Loja'!$A$6:$BJ$30000

I don't know if It is a excel configuration problem... Maybe a problem with that Single Quotes that appear on the beggining? I am not sure, have tried to remove them but still getting the error.

Comment: Try using R1C1 format to reference the range. In your example - `$A$6:$BJ$30000` would become `R6C1:R30000C62`

Comment: Also try using the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-2841ba85-9da6-4bd7-93a4-0da90844f283#bmrecordmacro) to capture the action you want to complete. It's usually a simple syntax issue like this that the macro record will smooth over ( albeit likely with a _LOT_ of extra code padded on ).